# Like Google Sign Up / Login - Email Validation Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, email-validation

I was stuck in a `regex` expression, I need to validate the **email address** based on the following criteria or you could say Google Username Rules:

[Create a Username - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9211434?hl=en)

- Choose a username `6–30` characters long.
- Usernames can contain `letters (a-z)`, `numbers (0-9)`, and `periods (.)`.
- Usernames ***cannot*** contain an `ampersand (&)`, `equals sign (=)`, `underscore (_)`, `apostrophe (')`, `dash (-)`, `plus sign (+)`, `comma (,)`, `brackets (<,>)`, or more than one period (.) in a row like `(..)`.
- Usernames can `begin or end` with non-alphanumeric characters except `periods (.)`.

So far I have the following : `/^([a-z0-9]+)([\.{1}])?([a-z0-9]+)\@(([a-z0-9-])+\.)+([a-z0-9]{2,4})/g` working fine ***until*** `test.user@test.co` (match `just two words` concatenating with a period (`.`) ). What about? `test.test.test@test.com`.

I mean what if more than two words occurred like `my.test.email.123@example.com` ? this should be validate as well.

```js
let email = document.getElementById("email")

//function - validate `email`
email.onkeyup = () => {
  if (email.value === "" || email.value === null) {
    console.log("Please enter your email.")
    return false
  } else if (!email.value.match(/^([a-z0-9]+)([\.{1}])?([a-z0-9]+)\@(([a-z0-9-])+\.)+([a-z0-9]{2,4})/g)) {
    console.log(`${email.value} - is an invalid email address!`)
    return false
  } else if (email.value !== "" && email.value !== null && email.value.match(/^([a-z0-9]+)([\.{1}])?([a-z0-9]+)\@(([a-z0-9-])+\.)+([a-z0-9]{2,4})/g)) {
    console.log("Email OK.")
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    input {
      margin: 0;
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      height: 30px;
      width: 250px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Please enter your email" autofocus required>
</body>

</html>
```

I've read 15+ answers but didn't find a useful one. Can anyone assist with a recommendation/alternative approach or point out what's wrong with this `regex` ? First rule is not mandatory but appreciated if its added too. Please provide the right `regex` for achieving the given rules and best results .

Answer (score 0):

Just correct the regex expression.

```
    let email = document.getElementById("email")

   //function - validate `email`
   email.onkeyup = () => {
    if (email.value === "" || email.value === null) {
     console.log("Please enter your email.")
     return false
     } else if (!email.value.match(/^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/)) {
      console.log(`${email.value} - is an invalid email address!`)
      return false
     } else if (email.value !== "" && email.value !== null && 
   email.value.match(/^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/)) {
   console.log("Email OK.")
  }
 }
```

Change this

```
/^([a-z0-9]+)([\.{1}])?([a-z0-9]+)\@(([a-z0-9-])+\.)+([a-z0-9]{2,4})/g
```

To this

```
/^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/
```

Comment: I appreciate your quick response, but this is not something that I want. It will allow me / the user to enter any email like `te---st.123.-john...doe-.@te.com` or another.

Comment: @TabassamAli u can try this

`var regex = /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$/;`

Comment: @GawiSh Thanks, but I prefer my current regex: `/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/` and it works well for me.